# Bold Text in Dialog Box - DXL

Tags: formatting, format, dialog, ibm-doors

I'm trying to make an program in DXL whos asks the user some data. For this reason, I would like show the instruction to user with an Dialog Box. How can I do put a bold strings in the Dialog Box? (I'm new in this language).

Although the question is already answered, I update the question so that future readers can understand it better:

I know how dialog boxes are created and displayed in DXL, as follows:

```
DB dialog = create("My DB box.", styleCentered | styleFixed);
label(dialog, "ALL");
show dialogue
```

But what I want to do is add bold text inside it.

Comment: How are all these very different languages related to this? Please do not spam with loads of unrelated tags.

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on where you need the bold text. As far as I know it is e.g. not possible to make a label of a field bold, but you could perhaps create a DBE of type `richField`  (or `richText`) on your dialog box and fill it with richtext, like in

```dxl
void doSomething (DBE x) {ack "boo!"}
DB dialog = create("hi there")
richField (dialog, "", "Remember to {\\b save your module} before calling this function", 60, true)
button (dialog, "Do something", doSomething)
show dialog
```

For more complex texts you might want to look at drawing text on a `DBE canvas`